# ¿Cómo puedo descomprimir un archivo deb con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, debian

necesito descomprimir o acceder a los archivos que se encuentran dentro de un archivo DEB. Para archivos de otro tipo como ZIP, GZIP o BZ2 sería de las siguientes formas:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    myzip.extractall()
```

Para los GZIP:

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
f.close()
```

Y para los BZ2:

```
import bz2
f_in = open("test.txt.bz2", "rb")
f_out = open("test.txt", "wb")
f_out.write(bz2.decompress(f_in.read()))
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

No encuentro como realizar estos procedimientos para los archivos DEB

Comment: https://deb-pkg-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Los ficheros .deb de debian son en realidad ficheros de tipo ar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix). Deberías poder extraerlos con dicha utilidad. Se supone que podrás: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patool

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas, voy a probar con patool. Específicamente necesito acceder al changelog del archivo deb

Comment: @Jorge, ten en cuenta algunas cosas: (1) `patool` es un "wrapper" sobre los ejecutables de cada programa, vas a necesitar el comando `ar` de unix de todas formas. (2) Los paquetes DEB son contenedores similar a lo que son los paquetes TAR, donde los archivos se "pegan" uno atrás del otro, no tienen ninguna compresión "per-se", internamente lo que se guarda son 3 archivos TAR (que si pueden estar comprimidos). (3) Hay algo de código para  trabajar con estos archivos en este Git: https://github.com/remram44/unix_ar. El formato TAR ya lo entiende Python.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la libreria [pyunpack](https://pypi.org/project/pyunpack/)
que te permite descomprimir:

> bzip2 for BZIP2 archives). Supported formats: 7z (.7z), ACE (.ace), ALZIP (.alz), AR (.a), ARC (.arc), ARJ (.arj), BZIP2 (.bz2), CAB (.cab), compress (.Z), CPIO (.cpio), DEB (.deb), DMS (.dms), GZIP (.gz), LRZIP (.lrz), LZH (.lha, .lzh), LZIP (.lz), LZMA (.lzma), LZOP (.lzo), RPM (.rpm), RAR (.rar), RZIP (.rz), TAR (.tar), XZ (.xz), ZIP (.zip, .jar) and ZOO (.zoo)